# My question isn't getting answers. What can I do?

Tags: discussion

Question: [Application rarely completes loading in debug mode, but "run without debug" loads fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995902/application-rarely-completes-loading-in-debug-mode-but-run-without-debug-load)

Is it because there aren't any answers? It's frustrating to try and find a problem to this strange error, let alone mysterious downvotes.

Granted I haven't been active SO for a few months, but have I missed something?

Edit: To clarify I had -2 at the time. Just wan't sure if I was asking the question correctly. I knew it was a long shot that somebody would have experienced the same problem - just confused around the reasons why the -2. I'll just have to keep looking. Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean "what did I do wrong"? As in, "why didn't I get an answer yet"?

Comment: @Bart When the OP originally posted this question he had 2 downvotes for seemingly no reason.  Obviously this isn't the case anymore.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry Ah, thanks for that clarification. Looking at the [first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8995902/1) it seems a bit thin on information. Perhaps that caused the initial downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

You did nothing wrong. You don't get answers because people most likely don't know what's causing your problem, so they just take a guess and post it as comment.

You might try setting a Bounty to get more attention, but of course it's not certain you will get solution - it might be something local to your machine/installation/application.

As for downvotes, I assume people thought you didn't try hard enough to solve this yourself, your first revision was indeed lacking of any details and as you see you now have 3 upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

See the **What if I don't get an answer?** section in the faq:

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

> First, [make sure you’ve asked a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

TL;DR, nobody should care more than you about getting an answer to your question.